# mongodb inMemory engine available in the community edition?

Tags: mongodb, storage-engine, in-memory-database

I'm currently working with MongoDB 3.2.10 and I recently heard of the new "inMemory" engine. After some research I found that it was available in the Enterprise Edition since version 3.2.6, but I couldn't find any information on an eventual release in the community edition.

**So the question is:** do they plan to release the inMemory engine for the Community Edition? If they do, do we know when?

Comment: I'm not sure if a speculative question is on-topic for DBA. As at MongoDB 3.4 the [In-Memory Storage Engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/inmemory/) is only available in [MongoDB Enterprise Edition](https://www.mongodb.com/products/mongodb-enterprise-advanced).

Comment: @Stennie I'm not looking for speculations, I need a clear answer: yes, they plan to release it or no, they don't. If the info is not available I guess it means they don't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As at MongoDB 3.4, no plans have been announced to make the [In Memory Storage Engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/inmemory/) available in the MongoDB Community Edition. I suspect this is likely to remain as an Enterprise-only feature for the foreseeable future given the more niche use cases for in-memory storage, however the definitive source will be the mongodb.com website and any future major release announcements.

FYI, you can subscribe to driver/server release announcements via the [mongodb-announce](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mongodb-announce) group.